# WPA2-enterprise in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-8, wpa2

I want to connect to my school network through a hotspot called `utcpers`, with encryption, using WPA2-Enterprise.

I'm using a Broadcom 43224AGN 802.11a/b/g/n 2x2 wi-fi adapter.

Using Windows 7 and Ubuntu, I can connect with the same credentials and settings described [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7F7164F716889B49!823&authkey=!AB9USLCJ8tjvzKs), but Windows 8 fails to connect to this network.

The tracing logs are available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7F7164F716889B49!824&authkey=!AHYg-jnou82WgBg).

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: Driver/NIC model?

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing the windows 7 driver. It's a Broadcom 43224AGN 802.11a/b/g/n 2x2 Wi-Fi Adapter

Comment: It would be appreciated if you would add that as an answer, to help other people that come along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by  by installing the windows 7 driver.

Answer (score 3):

After countless hours with the IT department at my Uni and countless hours of remote control with the boys at MS, no one had a fix.  Then I found [an interesting article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2749073) that talked about compatibility of some routers' software with current Windows 8 software.

Since our Unis are unlikely to update the software for the network, downgrade your drivers to Windows 7 drivers. If you upgrade from Windows 8, this should be really easy (just rollback the driver). If not, it's still possible by downloading a driver that works (they are out there). I am running a 2010 MacBook Pro with Windows 8 using Boot Camp and I was able to find a Windows 7 driver that worked. After you have that driver, restart, get your network config in and connect. Unfortunately I have to log in every time my computer turns on or awakens from sleep, but hey, it's a connection, right?